# Shell: input for pdfinfo

Tags: fish

On a `fish` shell I write

```
ls -1t|head -1 |xargs pdfinfo
```

which should basically give me the latest modified file (which is a PDF) and then print the PDFinfo of this file. But somehow it fails with the error

```
Syntax Warning: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway)
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary
Syntax Error: Couldn't read xref table
```

I get the same results with `bash`. Any ideas what I need to adapt to get the command running?

Comment: Have you tried just running `pdfinfo` on the file manually? Does the filename include spaces or quotes? `xargs` typically splits on any kind of whitespace and parses quotes, which is unlikely to be what you want. Try just `pdfinfo (ls -1t)[1]`.

Comment: `pdfinfo (ls -1t)[1]` helps definitely - meaning I would accept it as well as answer. Note: The file doesn't contain any kind of space. Q: What does the `[1]` mean? The first entry of the resultset?
Thx for your help

Comment: Yes, the `[1]` takes only the first *line* of the output - fish splits command substitutions on newlines only. Can you give the output of `ls -1t | head -1 | xargs printf '<%s>\n'` and `ls -1t | head -n 1 | string escape`? That would explain how xargs borks it up. I do strongly believe there's some character here that confuses it.

Comment: I have to confess that I don't know how to reproduce the situation :-| I feel little bit ashamed to cause some efforts for solving an issue which I cannot reproduce any longer :-/ Anyway thx

Comment: If I had to guess: `ls -1t` sorts by modification time (by default). So if you modify a file that would cause a different file to bubble to the top. My money is still on the filename breaking xargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is most likely down to `xargs` mangeling its input.

By default, it will perform bash-like word splitting, including quotes.

So for instance

```
echo "foo 'bar baz'" | xargs printf '<%s>\n'
```

Will print `<foo>` and `<bar baz>`, as it will execute like

```
printf '<%s>\n' foo 'bar baz'
```

That means if you have a filename with a space or quote, it will execute the wrong thing. Assuming "ls -1t | head -n 1", which prints the newest file, comes up with "foo bar.pdf", then it would execute pdfinfo like

```
pdfinfo foo bar.pdf
```

handing it two separate filenames, "foo" and "bar.pdf".

In this case, the simplest solution is to just skip xargs entirely:

```
pdfinfo (ls -1t | head -n 1)
```

You can also skip the `head` by using fish's slicing:

```
pdfinfo (ls -1t)[1]
```

which will only take the first line of `ls -1t`s output. Note that fish will still split on newlines (unlike bash it won't split on spaces or tabs), so if you wanted to handle filenames with newlines (which can typically happen on unix!) you would have to do it differently - the `ls` output is ambiguous if filenames can include newlines. Possibilities include `find` with `-exec`.

If you *have* to use xargs, you can use the `-0` option that is available in some xargs implementations, together with fish's `string join0` to add a NUL-byte:

```
 ls -1t | head -n1 | string join0 | xargs -0 pdfinfo
```

This will tell xargs to inhibit its word splitting and instead read arguments NUL-terminated (which is unambiguous because UNIX filenames and commandline arguments in general can't include NUL - because it passes them as NUL-terminated strings).